# What is the default or starting directory for a VS solution?

Tags: c++, image, gdi+

## My Scenario:

I want to use an image file, "ship.png",  in a project I am working on in Visual Studio 2013.

Every path I use returns NULL, so I am confused on where to start my path string. I am trying to load it into an object of type GDI+ class 'Image' by using "FromFile()".

```
// image is defined previously and is a Image*.
image = Image::FromFile(L"ship.png");
// When I debug, image is still NULL like it is when it is initialized.
```

## My Question:

**What directory does the program begin in?** I would assume the exe file, but I tried using a path curtailed to that scenario and it still returned NULL. 
I have also tried putting the image file directly into the directory where the solution file resides and the one where the exe file resides with the path "ship.png" and in both cases it is still NULL.

Any ideas? If you are experienced in GDI+ and have never heard of this, then I am probably doing something wrong with it, as it has a very confusing and convoluted (in my opinion) API.

## Solution for Specified Problem Found:

I needed to insert the following code before the action:

```
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
```

And this code after:

```
GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

Now image is no longer null.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does it work if you give the absolute path of the image file? Perhaps there is another reason for the null return?

Comment: [`_getcwd` will tell you your program's working directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx). Don't count on it being the same as the executable because there are many, many ways to run a program from a different location.

Comment: ***What directory does the program begin in?*** If you are using the Visual Studio IDE this is set in the debugger settings. The default setting is the folder contains the project file. However as @user4581301 said the path will vary depending on how you run the program so if you distribute your program to someone else don't count on the folder being the same. You need to check first.

Comment: *"Every path I use returns NULL"* The file has only one full path. Use the full path, for example `L"C:\\test\\test.png"`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Isn't that kind of bad form? If I gave this to someone else, they may install it anywhere on their disk, not to mention they will almost certainly have differently named folders than me. Isn't it good to create your paths relative to the project's own folders?

Comment: @Ben Yes, there very well could be, however I have had this question even before running into this problem, so I needed to know. Plus, Stackexchange's community seems usually hostile to scenario-based questions rather than general ones.

Comment: @Ben The problem was that I apparently need to start up GDI every time I do anything with it, regardless if it was already started in another part of the code. But having the right path is also crucial. ;D

Comment: Dont add the answer to the question. Add it as an answer and accept your own answer in 2 days if that is what ended up being the solution.

Comment: *"If I gave this to someone else, they may install it anywhere on their disk"* The installation program sets the directories and the information is saved. This has nothing to do with your question. Use the full path name to eliminate file not found error.

Comment: @Ben What I put in the answer was the solution to my specific problem. It has nothing to do with the core question.

Comment: This community and their down votes.. geez why do I even bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default place where VS would look for that file is directory with your source files (*.cpp files)

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you very much.